# Ignore some locations in Windbg Conditional breakpoints

Tags: windbg, breakpoint

I'm trying to set a conditional hardware breakpoint on Windows Kernel-Mode in Windbg by using the following syntax :

```
ba w1 ffff802312345678 "j(@rip==ffff802387654321 || @rip==ffff802387654330) 'gc';''"
```

I used the above command in order to ignore every access to my target location (`ffff802312345678`) from `ffff802387654321` or `ffff802387654330`, so everytime access from somewhere else is taken, then I would be notified.

But the problem is, it still breaks on `ffff802387654321` or  `ffff802387654330` among the other locations.

I also read it's [official documents](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/setting-a-conditional-breakpoint) about "**Conditional Breakpoints and Register Sign Extension**" and also test something like this:

```
ba w1 ffff802312345678 "j((@rip & 0xffffffffffffffff)=ffff802387654321 || (@rip & 0xffffffffffffffff)=ffff802387654330) 'gc';''"
```

But it still won't work.

So my question is:

- What's wrong with the above command and how can I achieve the desired
  result ?